# React tutorial: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following React tutorial at: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

I'm just **after** http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#fetching-from-the-server

I went through similar questions on SO but not found a solution for my specific case.

```
var data = [
    {author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
    {author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *another* comment"},
    {author: "Bob Lilly", text: "This is *another* comment 2"}

];

var Comment = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
        return (
            <div className="comment">
                <h2 className="commentAuthor">
                    {this.props.author}
                </h2>
                <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
            return (
                <Comment author={comment.author}>
                    {comment.text}
                </Comment>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
                {commentNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="commentForm">
                <br/>Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList data={this.props.data} /> 
                <CommentForm />
            </div>
        );
    }
});


React.render(
    // <CommentBox url="comments.json" />, 
    <CommentBox data={data} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

When I try to use data got from server (first step  --> see 2nd link), I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

I guess this has something to do with passing data the wrong way.

**EDIT**: I edited the cod with the answers given so far

**EDIT 2**: Now it works with dumb data (var data = [ ... ) but not when got from the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding that line will not get data from the server.  You need to work all the way down to the end of the "Reactive State" section, creating the data file, and adding some ajax code to load the data.

Answer (score 4):

You're sending `data` as a prop to `CommentBox` and trying to pass it on through `CommentBox` state.

```
<CommentList data={this.props.data} />
```

instead of

```
<CommentList data={this.state.data} />
```

I usually reason about props this way; Props are stuff coming in and State is stuff that's already in.

Comment: actually that's a typo (don't know why). Anyhow in render: function() of CommentList I tried console.log(this.props); and it prints Object {data: undefined} but the error is still there

Comment: I managed to make it work with dumb data, but not server data. see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You're sending `data` via props to `CommentBox` and checking for it in your `CommentList` component

Comment: I don't get it. can you be more precise? (also see my edit please)

Comment: I managed to make it work with dumb data, but not server data. see my edit